# How can I account for identical data points in a scatter plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm working with some data that has several identical data points.  I would like to visualize the data in a scatter plot, but scatter plotting doesn't do a good job of showing the duplicates.

If I change the alpha value, then the identical data points become darker, which is nice, but not ideal.

Is there some way to map the color of a dot to how many times it occurs in the data set?  What about size?  How can I assign the size of the dot to how many times it occurs in the data set?

Comment: What do you not like about using alpha?  A disadvantage of the other approaches you suggest is that they rely on counting exactly-equal values.  But you may have many *almost* equal values that overlap on the scatter plot.  Any approach that involves counting individual values will not improve the plot, but using alpha will, since partially overlapping points will still result in darkening.

Answer (score 3):

As it was pointed out, whether this makes sense depends a bit on your dataset. If you have reasonably discrete points and exact matches make sense, you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
test_x=[2,3,4,1,2,4,2]
test_y=[1,2,1,3,1,1,1]   #  I am just generating some test x and y values. Use your data here
#Generate a list of unique points
points=list(set(zip(test_x,test_y))) 
#Generate a list of point counts
count=[len([x for x,y in zip(test_x,test_y) if x==p[0] and y==p[1]]) for p in points]
#Now for the plotting:
plot_x=[i[0] for i in points]
plot_y=[i[1] for i in points]
count=np.array(count)
plt.scatter(plot_x,plot_y,c=count,s=100*count**0.5,cmap='Spectral_r')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Notice: You will need to adjust the radius (the value `100` in th `s` argument) according to your point density. I also used the square root of the count to scale it so that the point area is proportional to the counts.

Also note: If you have very dense points, it might be more appropriate to use a different kind of plot. Histograms for example (I personally like `hexbin` for 2d data) are a decent alternative in these cases.

Comment: Is it possible to apply this code for 3D scatter plot? I already used this code for 2D scatter plot but now i would like to add 3rd dimension. I already tried but it returns me an error in a line generating a list of point counts.